# Rails Asset Pipeline CSS different on remote than in development

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline, cssbundling-rails

I'm having a small issue where my compiled CSS on my deployed app is ever so slightly different to the compiled CSS locally in Development.  Thankfully it's causing one minor problem.

I'm using cssbundling-rails to compile my SASS and to output the file into the `assets/builds` directory.

If, when I deploy my app, the CSS gets compiled on the server, is it right that the files in my `assets/builds` directory locally get committed into my git repo?

Should I exclude them?   If so then what do I add to my `.gitignore` file?

I'm just unsure what to ignore and what should and should not be committed etc when using that gem.

Answer (score 0):

I think, `assets/builds` is committed, but `public/assets` is by default excluded in your .gitignore.

When you deploy your app, rails compiles the assets automatically [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline).

If you want to be sure it is the same, you could delete the `public/assets` folder and run `rails assets:precompile` directly before deploying.